# Tensorflow 2.0 tf.keras.layers.Conv2D unable to take input images

Tags: tensorflow2.0

#### Trying to define a model in Tensorflow 2.0 using Keras APIs. The first layer is a 2D-convolution layer with input RGB-image with dimension (127, 127) as shown in the following code. Actually, I am trying to implement the 3D-R2N2 in TF 2.x and there will be branches at some processes so tf.keras.Sequential() is not helpful at all.

#### Tried to find some clue from their(Google TF) doc for rc2.0 but its so broken. The input_shape=(127,127,3) is suggested by the doc for Conv2D while it contributes nothing at all. Searches on the doc. always mix-up with 1.x versions which sucks, seems like they are not prepared for a release at all. Please accept for some reasons I have to try it on TF 2.x.

#### Can someone else please help?

```html
ims = tf.convert_to_tensor(value=images[0])
ims = tf.reshape(ims,[-1,127,127,3])
#ims = ims.numpy() #ims.eval()#

# tf.disable_eager_execution()

#####################################################################################################################
# Define the layers of the Model

# Define the input layer
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(127,127,3))

# n_convfilter[0] = 96, n_convfilter[1] = 128 ...
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape=(127, 127, 3), filters=[7, 7, 3, n_convfilter[0]], kernel_size=[7,7], kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.VarianceScaling(2.0), strides=[1,1], bias_initializer='zeros', padding="same", data_format="channels_last")(inputs)
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(conv1)
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(conv1)

# Convolutional Layer #2
conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( filters=[3,3,n_convfilter[0],n_convfilter[1]], kernel_size=[3,3], kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.VarianceScaling(2.0), strides=[1,1], bias_initializer='zeros', padding="SAME")(conv1)
conv2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(conv2)
conv2 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(conv2)
...
# conv_i to branches and merge back
branch0 =  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8192, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, use_bias=True )( conv_i )
branch0 = tf.reshape(branch0, [4, 4, 4, -1, 128]) 

branch1 =  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8192, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, use_bias=True )( conv_i )
branch1 = tf.reshape(branch1, [4, 4, 4, -1, 128]) 

...
branch_m =  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8192, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, use_bias=True )( conv_i )
branch_m = tf.reshape(branch_m, [4, 4, 4, -1, 128]) 

# Merges with HyperParams
merge0 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3d(HyperParams, weights['for_branch0'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME") + branch0
merge0 = tf.add(merge0, biases['for_branch0']) 
merge0_gate = tf.sigmoid(merge0)
...
```

```
--> conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=[7, 7, 3, n_convfilter[0]], kernel_size=[7,7], strides=[1,1], padding="same", data_format="channels_last", kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.VarianceScaling(2.0), bias_initializer='zeros', input_shape=(127, 127, 3))(inputs)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ListWrapper'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. By a genius friend pointing out my mistake on the arguments.

> filters is no longer a tensor in TF 2.x